# GLSL - Test Fragment Values

Tags: glsl

Say you have a `vec3 colourIn` going from a `vertex shader` to a `frag shader`, is there a way to test a value and overwrite it if you want to?

For example, set any fragment that has a blue value larger than 0.5 to the colour white?

In my `Shader.frag` I implemented this test:

```
    if(colourIn.b>0.5){ //or if(greaterThan(colourIn.b,0.5))
     colourIn.b=0.0;
    }
```

It compiles and renders the scene, but I can't tell if it's worked because I'm colourblind (lol)... Have I got the theory right and implemented it correctly?

[image: cubes]

Comment: I've already answered, and am sure your code is correct, but if you can supply a screenshot then you could be really confident. I'm not sure if you're allowed to add them inline to your posts with 218 points but if you can put it anywhere online then someone else can edit your question to include it.

Answer (score 0):

You could directly write the conditional if you wanted, and your example should be correct, but a smarter move might be something like:

```
float mixValue = clamp(floor(colourIn.b * 2.0), 0.0, 1.0);
colourIn.b = mix(colourIn.b, 0.0, mixValue);

// the floor will be:
//     0.0 for [0.0 — 0.5);
//     1.0 for [0.5, 1.0)
//     2.0 1.0
//
// so the clamp will make mixValue:
//     0.0 for [0.0, 0.5]
//     1.0 for (0.5, 1.0]
//
// if you were to multiply by 1.99 then you could
// get rid of the clamp but if the input is a 
// GLubyte then that'd move 128 into the low group
// instead of the high one
```

Which avoids the conditional and therefore any related pipeline stalls or parallelisation breakdowns.

Comment: Thanks for posting. Good explanation! It should certainly do the trick. Unfortunately it doesn't compile when I use the above code in my `.frag`. I'm now having a play with it, I'm probably doing something very stupid. (It's been a long day). It makes a lot of sense though, and certainly more efficient than my test.

Comment: @Reanimation it's more likely I've made a mistake — the code was written extemporaneously, without testing. Have you got the actual error to hand? The image you added has a cube with quite a lot of blue on the left and almost no blue on the right if that helps.

Comment: Ok thanks, it's any blue on the left cube I'm testing and hoping to change. I've just got back to my program and tested your code and it produces the error: `ERROR: 0:16 error(164) 1-value required assigned "colourIn" (can't modify an input)` so I'm guessing your code is correct (looks it and makes sense), but the value cannot be adjusted for some reason...

Comment: @Reanimation sorry, yes, I copied the assignment directly from your working code, assuming the variable was read/write. Correct as necessary.